# facebook graph api "since" param does not work for Instagram comments, what is the alternative solution to get all new comments in one request?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, filter, pagination, comments, instagram

I'm trying to fetch instagram comments trough the facebook graph api and I set the "since" parameter as follows:

[https://graph.facebook.com/{mediaId}/comments?fields=id,text,timestamp,from,replies&since=2023-05-16T21:25:19+0000&access_token={token}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7BmediaId%7D/comments?fields=id,text,timestamp,from,replies&since=2023-05-16T21:25:19+0000&access_token=%7Btoken%7D)

but it returns all comments. how can I fetch all newly added comments if its not working by date filtering????

As mentioned in official docs cursors also can be easily invalidated and shouldnt be stored to be used later!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, seems that you need to tell it what order you need this returned in:

[https://graph.facebook.com/{mediaId}/comments?fields=id,text,timestamp,from,replies&since=2023-05-16T21:25:19+0000&access_token={token}&order=chronilogical](https://graph.facebook.com/%7BmediaId%7D/comments?fields=id,text,timestamp,from,replies&since=2023-05-16T21:25:19+0000&access_token=%7Btoken%7D&order=chronilogical)

Try that, see it helps.